# Text not displayed when mouse is rolled over JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

With NetBeans (Java), I am having problems in JLabel. I have assigned an image as the icon of that JLabel.

Problem - 1st:

I want to display some text (e.g - logout) below that icon (image). How to do this?

Problem - 2nd:

I want to display some text when mouse is rolled over that JLabel. What should I do?

So , please guys tell me how to these things by writing code.

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1.

Create a `JPanel` that contains two `JLabel`s. This way you can control the layout of the internal components.

I used `BoxLayout` with the parameter `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` to get the label below the icon.

### 2.

Add a `MouseListener` using the method `component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { ... });`, you'll need to create a [`MouseAdapter` and implement any methods you need (click here)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).

Here is a working example for you buddy... Adapt this however you need to.

Note: You'll need to change the `file-path` of the `ImageIcon()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    JPanel iconLabelPanel = new JPanel();

    String TEXT_FIELD_TEXT = "Hover over the logout label.";

    JLabel icon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gary\\Google Drive\\Pictures\\puush\\ss (2015-02-19 at 06.00.00).png"));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Logout!");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(TEXT_FIELD_TEXT);

    //Add a mouse motion listener for the JLabel
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            //Set text of another component
            textField.setText("You're over Logout!");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            //Set text of another component
            textField.setText(TEXT_FIELD_TEXT);
        }
    });


    //Add components and set parameters for iconLabelPanel
    iconLabelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(iconLabelPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    iconLabelPanel.add(icon);
    iconLabelPanel.add(label);

    //Add components and set parameters for container
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    container.add(iconLabelPanel);
    container.add(textField);

    //Set parameters for frame
    frame.add(container);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: hi gary ..i am new to forum .so i don't know how to mark it

Comment: Check the tick shaped image next to an answer. Like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the basic Oracle tutorials which describe in detail how to accomplish this. You can use a [MouseMotionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) to determine when the mouse is rolled over the JLabel, and you can position the JLabel text underneath the Icon of the JLabel by setting its vertical text position as described in the [JLabel Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). This should have all been found with a simple internet search of your questions, something that your question suggests was not done (and should have been) before asking

Comment: Why use a `MouseMotionListener`? Why not just `setToolTipText("Whatever op wanted here")`

Comment: Depends what the OP wants. Yes, the tool tip will overlay text on top of the JLabel, but that wasn't the original requirement ('display text below the icon'). A MouseMotionListener provides the flexibility to not only change the JLabel text, but respond in other ways as well.